# Different between calling to function by delegate or by instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

What are the different between calling to a function by delegate or by creating an instance and calling tomethod:

for example, I can use the next method

```
ViewC1.m

-(void) doSomthing{
}


viewC2.m

viewC1 *myInterface = [[viewC1 alloc] init];
[myInterface doSomthing];
```

or creating delegate with protocol... and use it like this:

```
viewC2.m

[self.delegate doSomthing];
```

Comment: In this line `viewC1 *myInterface = [viewC1 alloc];` I think you mean `viewC1 *myInterface = [[viewC1 alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

It's primarily a question of the design pattern that you're trying to achieve.  Delegation allows you to create less explicit linkages between classes.  From Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2):

> "Protocols free method declarations from dependency on the class
>   hierarchy, so they can be used in ways that classes and categories
>   cannot. Protocols list methods that are (or may be) implemented
>   somewhere, but the identity of the class that implements them is not
>   of interest."

So, to answer your question, there's no difference on an outcome basis, so long as `self.delegate` exists and implements `doSomthing` and `viewC1` instances implement `doSomthing`.  But without knowing the broader context, it's hard to say much more about the relative advantages.  I'd read up on Objective-C protocols and about the delegate pattern as heavily used in the Cocoa frameworks to get a better feel for when to use this pattern.  Follow Apple's lead in this case.

(By the way, in Objective-C, it's "methods" instead of "functions"...)

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are two class ViewC1 and ViewC2. If you want to send message from ViewC1 to ViewC2 and receive the callback message from ViewC2 to ViewC1. It is better using protocol for this objects communication. If you using instance method for this objects communication, you will restricted ViewC2 to callback on specified object (In this case ViewC1). In order to let ViewC2 able to callback any objects. You can define the protocol on ViewC2. And let other object which want to receive the callback to conform it.